# Power set intersection proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In book "Naive Set Theory" I am asked to prove that intersection of power sets is equal to power set of intersection

$P(E) \cap P(F) = P(E \cap F)$

I am not sure if I got definition of power sets right, so is it like that I need to prove the following thing?

$(x \in X \to  x \in E) \cap (x \in X \to x \in F) = (x \in X \to x \in E \cap x \in F)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of two sets $A$ and $B$ is the supremum of all sets which are included both in $A$ and $B$:
$$\forall C\  (C\subseteq A\wedge C\subseteq B)\longrightarrow C\subseteq A\cap B$$
This defines $A\cap B$ uniquely, thanks to the antisymmetric property of set-inclusion.

In your case, $A=P(E), B=P(F)$ and your claim is $P(E\cap F)=P(E)\cap P(F)$. So you have to prove that:
$$\forall C \ (C\subseteq P(E)\wedge C\subseteq P(F))\longrightarrow C\subseteq P(E\cap F)$$
which is pretty easy to do.